# LEFT JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a LEFT JOIN in MS Access that has two conditions in it. However, when running below code I get "JOIN expression not supported". Would anybody know how to fix? The issue is in the part "d.brand=c.brand". But I don't know how to rewrite it...

```
SELECT 
     a.WeekNo, a.EssbaseCustomer, a.SKU, a.SKU_Description, c.[Brand], d.Index, 
     a.Promo_Kg, a.Promo_NSV, b.NonPromo_NSVkg, a.Promo_NSV/a.Promo_kg AS 
     Promo_NSVkg
FROM 
     ((Actuals AS a LEFT JOIN PriceList AS b ON (a.SKU=b.SKU) 
     AND (a.EssbaseCustomer=b.EssbaseCustomer)) LEFT JOIN Map_SKU 
     AS c ON a.SKU=c.SKU) LEFT JOIN Seasonality AS d ON a.Weekno=d.Weekno 
     AND d.brand=c.Brand
WHERE 
     a.Promo_Kg>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in a misplaced parenthesis

```
SELECT a.WeekNo,
       a.EssbaseCustomer,
       a.SKU,
       a.SKU_Description,
       c.[Brand],
       d.Index,
       a.Promo_Kg,
       a.Promo_NSV,
       b.NonPromo_NSVkg,
       a.Promo_NSV/a.Promo_kg AS Promo_NSVkg
FROM ((Actuals AS a
       LEFT JOIN PriceList AS b ON (a.SKU=b.SKU) AND (a.EssbaseCustomer=b.EssbaseCustomer))
       LEFT JOIN Map_SKU AS c ON a.SKU=c.SKU
       LEFT JOIN Seasonality AS d ON a.Weekno=d.Weekno AND d.brand=c.Brand)
WHERE a.Promo_Kg>0;
```

Or better yet, no parenthesis at all:

```
SELECT a.WeekNo,
       a.EssbaseCustomer,
       a.SKU,
       a.SKU_Description,
       c.[Brand],
       d.Index,
       a.Promo_Kg,
       a.Promo_NSV,
       b.NonPromo_NSVkg,
       a.Promo_NSV/a.Promo_kg AS Promo_NSVkg
FROM Actuals AS a
        LEFT JOIN PriceList AS b ON a.SKU=b.SKU AND a.EssbaseCustomer=b.EssbaseCustomer
        LEFT JOIN Map_SKU AS c ON a.SKU=c.SKU
        LEFT JOIN Seasonality AS d ON a.Weekno=d.Weekno AND d.brand=c.Brand
WHERE a.Promo_Kg>0;
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Paranthesis are redundant. Also, I moved the where clause into first left join which is relevant there

```
SELECT 
     a.WeekNo, a.EssbaseCustomer, a.SKU, a.SKU_Description, c.[Brand], d.Index, 
     a.Promo_Kg, a.Promo_NSV, b.NonPromo_NSVkg, a.Promo_NSV/a.Promo_kg AS 
     Promo_NSVkg
FROM Actuals AS a
LEFT JOIN PriceList AS b 
  ON a.SKU=b.SKU AND a.EssbaseCustomer = b.EssbaseCustomer and a.Promo_Kg>0
LEFT JOIN Map_SKU AS c 
  ON a.SKU=c.SKU 
LEFT JOIN Seasonality AS d 
  ON a.Weekno=d.Weekno 
 AND d.brand=c.Brand
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for thinking with me! This code from Johannes does not work (I had to put parenthesis as MS Access requires it):

```
SELECT a.WeekNo,
   a.EssbaseCustomer,
   a.SKU,
   a.SKU_Description,
   c.[Brand],
   d.Index,
   a.Promo_Kg,
   a.Promo_NSV,
   b.NonPromo_NSVkg,
   a.Promo_NSV/a.Promo_kg AS Promo_NSVkg
FROM (((Actuals AS a
    LEFT JOIN PriceList AS b ON a.SKU=b.SKU AND a.EssbaseCustomer=b.EssbaseCustomer)
    LEFT JOIN Map_SKU AS c ON a.SKU=c.SKU)
    LEFT JOIN Seasonality AS d ON a.Weekno=d.Weekno AND d.brand=c.Brand)
WHERE a.Promo_Kg>0;
```

But when removing "d.brand=c.Brand" it works. So there is something wrong.